# combining listings and tufte-book, listings caption on tufte's margin

Tags: listings, positioning, captions, tufte

I am not very familiar with all latex details, but I'd like to use the `listings` package in a tufte-book document. However, the `listings` package places its captions above or below the listing and I couldn't find a way to adjust that in a way so that the caption is put to the page margin as with tufte-book's `\marginnote` etc.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: This does not work with labels for line number references, see ["Use listings in tufte-book with captions in margin"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282485/93842)

Answer (score 3):

It is best neither to mess with the listings or the tufte-book commands, as they are both difficult to modify. I would simply load the listing in a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` environment. If you want to have a different float for listings, you can use the `float` package.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}
This is a test
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{This is a test.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the above answer, this is what I use now:

```
\newcommand{\cpplistinc}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
    \begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting[style=C++11,caption={}]{../src/ch\thechapter/#1}
    \caption{#1}
    \label{ch\thechapter/#1}
    \index{#1 in chapter \thechapter } % might use a separate index for that.
    \end{figure}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
    }
```